# How to prepareForSegue with NSFetchedResults drilldown to another tableview with objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I know there is probably a very simple solution to this. I'm using the apple iphoneCoreDataRecipes example. I'm trying to drill down from an initial table(RecipeTypeTableViewController) of RecipeTypes (ie Beverage, Dessert, Entree) to the next tableview with listing of those type of Recipes(RecipeListTableViewController). I created a new class RecipeType, thinking I could just use this to return recipes of a selected RecipeType. So far the best I can get is allowing selection but it is showing the same list of all recipes. The original code starts with RecipeListTableViewController using NSFetchedResults to show all recipes. Now I have the initial view of RecipeTypes but I'm not sure how to pass the selected type to RecipeListTableViewController. I need to change RecipeListTableViewController to show list of the selected RecipeType but I'm not sure how to implement this. I think I basically want to pass an NSMutableArray of fetchedresults to another tableview but not sure which direction to take. And I don't want to mess up other working actions in the RecipeListTableViewController, ie search and editing of recipes. Here's images of table action so far [RecipeTypeTableView][1] & [RecipeListTableview][2]. Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Deleted these

File: RecipeType.h

File: RecipeType.m

I use the NSManagedObject *type from my Recipe Class NSManagedObject to create initial view of recipe types(Appetizer, Bev, etc.) on the RecipeTypeTableViewController -

File: Recipe.h

```
@interface Recipe : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObject *type;
```

File: RecipeTypeTableViewController.h

```
//  RecipeTypeTableViewController.h
//  Recipes
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface RecipeTypeTableViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObject *type;
@end
```

File: RecipeTypeTableViewController.m  - the prepare for segue part

```
#import "RecipeTypeTableViewController.h"
#import "Recipe.h"
#import "RecipeListTableViewController.h"
@interface RecipeTypeTableViewController () <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@end

@implementation RecipeTypeTableViewController

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"showRecipes";

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// register this class for our cell to this table view under the specified identifier 'ARecipeType'
self.title = @"Category";
//[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ARecipeType"];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didChangePreferredContentSize:)name:UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification object:nil];
// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {

    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    //abort();
}
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
self.title = @"Category";

}

- (void)didChangePreferredContentSize:(NSNotification *)notification
{
[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
#pragma mark - Table view data source

//- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
//#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
//return [[self.recipeTypeFetchedResultsController sections] count];

//    return 1;
//}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Number of rows is the number of recipe types
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
//return self.recipeTypes.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ARecipeType" forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell
NSManagedObject *recipeType = [self.recipeTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [recipeType valueForKey:@"name"]; 
return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

// Set up the fetched results controller if needed.
if (_fetchedResultsController == nil) {
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RecipeType" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entity);

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Recipe"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}

return _fetchedResultsController;
}

#pragma mark - Navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showRecipes"]) {
    NSLog(@"Setting RecipeType for the RecipeListTableViewController");
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    Recipe *selectedType = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    RecipeListTableViewController *recipeListViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    recipeListViewController.type = selectedType;
    recipeListViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
}
}
```

File: RecipeListTableViewController.h - the NSPredicate part and the FRC cache

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RecipeAddViewController.h"

@interface RecipeListTableViewController : UITableViewController <RecipeAddDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObject *type;
```

File: RecipeListTableViewController.m

```
#import "RecipeListTableViewController.h"
#import "RecipeDetailViewController.h"
#import "Recipe.h"
#import "RecipeTableViewCell.h"
#import "Recipe+Extensions.h"
#import "TypeSelectionViewController.h"
#import "IngredientDetailViewController.h"
#import "Ingredient.h"
#import "WhereViewController.h"
#import "FavoriteListTableViewController.h"
#import "RecipeTypeTableViewController.h"
#import "RecipeType.h"


@interface RecipeListTableViewController () <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *filteredList;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchRequest *searchFetchRequest;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, RecipesSearchScope)
{
searchScopeRecipe = 0,
searchScopeIngredients = 1
};


@end

@implementation RecipeListTableViewController


#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

// Set up the fetched results controller if needed.
if (_fetchedResultsController == nil) {
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Recipe" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Recipe"];

    // Create predicate
    //if (self.type) {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type == %@", self.type];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    //}


    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Recipe"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}

return _fetchedResultsController;
}

/
```

When I have the FRC cache set to "Recipe". It crashes. It showed this clue to look at cache   CoreData: FATAL ERROR: The persistent cache of section information does not match the current configuration.  You have illegally mutated the NSFetchedResultsController's fetch request, its predicate, or its sort descri...

If I set the cache to nil, or add [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Recipe"]; before the predicate set, things work as expected. I have this cache in the inital view controller and the second view controller. Maybe that is the problem - I only need cache in the initial view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think your data model needs a little refinement.  Each `RecipeType` can presumably have many associated `Recipes`.  So the relationship from `RecipeType` to `Recipe` should be *to-many*.  If you change this in the data model editor, and regenerate the model classes, you should then have a RecipeType class that looks something like this:

```
@class Recipe;

@interface RecipeType : NSManagedObject
// not sure what purpose this property serves; it might now be superfluous...
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObject *type;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet<Recipe *> *recipes;

@end
```

I'll assume for the time being that each `Recipe` can belong to only one `RecipeType`.  So the inverse relationship, from `Recipe` to `RecipeType` should be *to-one*, and the `Recipe` class will therefore have a property:

```
*property (nonatomic, strong) RecipeType *type;
```

Next, you want your `RecipeListTableViewController` to display only the `Recipes` that are related to the relevant `RecipeType`.  To achieve that, you need to add a predicate to the fetched results controller.  In the `fetchedResultsController` method, add:

```
if (self.recipeType) {
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type == %@", self.recipeType];
}
```

(You will also need to amend your search to likewise limit the search to the relevant `RecipeType`).  In the `RecipeTypeTableViewContoller`, your `prepareForSegue` needs only to pass the correct `RecipeType`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {    
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showRecipes"]) {
        NSLog(@"Setting RecipeType for the RecipeListTableViewController");
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        RecipeType *selectedType = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        RecipeListTableViewController *recipeListViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        recipeListViewController.recipeType = selectedType;
        recipeListViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    }
}
```

Whenever you add a new `Recipe`, you will need to assign it to the correct `RecipeType`.  So in the `RecipeListViewController` amend your `prepareForSegue` to set the relationship:

```
...
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:kAddRecipeSegueID]) {
    // add a recipe
    //
    Recipe *newRecipe = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Recipe" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    newRecipe.type = self.recipeType;

    UINavigationController *navController = segue.destinationViewController;
    RecipeAddViewController *addController = (RecipeAddViewController *)navController.topViewController;
    addController.delegate = self;  // do didAddRecipe delegate method is called when cancel or save are tapped
    addController.recipe = newRecipe;
}
```

Comment: Your answer gets an A for accuracy. Top code spotting. Thank you....
It works. But then it doesn't and I accept this is not because your correct/not.

Comment: I reconfigured the RecipeType. Removing the subclass and using the existing NSManagedObject *type from the Recipe Class. I get my recipe type list and when I select Snack it shows 2 snack recipes. Awesome.

Comment: But then when I return to the category list and select another type it crashes. I restart the app sim and select another type and it pass the correct list. But I select a type that has no recipes it shows a blank table then if I return to select another type, even it there are some recipes it gives a blank table.  Sorry for multi comment  - return happy.

Comment: [code] @interface Recipe : NSManagedObject
[code]@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObject *type;
[code]@end  [code]// Create predicate
        if (self.type) {
        fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type == %@", self.type];
        //[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        }[code]

Comment: [code]- (void)prepareForSegue was 100% Thanks
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showRecipes"]) {
        NSLog(@"Setting RecipeType for the RecipeListTableViewController");
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Recipe *selectedType = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        RecipeListTableViewController *recipeListViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        recipeListViewController.type = selectedType;
        recipeListViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;[code]

Comment: @Chuck Not sure I understand your comments.  Have you ironed out the problems?  Let me know if there's anything outstanding.

Comment: Sorry yes I know I went cra cra with comments. Your answer of the segue and the predicate look accurate. Thanks  - After re-configured, The Recipe Class has NSManaged Object *type which I used and eliminated all reference to subclass RecipeType.  The new configuration shows the listing of types and when I select one it shows the correct type recipes. But when I return to the type listing and select another type it crashes. I can restart the simulator and select another type and it returns correctly.

Comment: But if I choose a type that has no recipes it gives a blank table as expected and if I return to the type list and select another type it returns all other types as blank. So it look like it works but only one time. Maybe the recipe type table needs reset on the return segue? Any suggestions Thank you again.

Comment: Not sure where to put `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet <Recipe *> *recipes;` now. I have it on the RecipeTypeTVC.h Also `@class Recipe` here. And  `@dynamic` on the RecipeTypeTVC.m. And not sure where does this ever get used?

Comment: the prepare segue gets the type now `Recipe *selectedType = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        RecipeListTableViewController *recipeListViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        recipeListViewController.type = selectedType;
        recipeListViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;`

Comment: OK set my NS Cache to nil - now works like a charm  `NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];'

Comment: so then leads to next how to keep the cache and implement deleteCacheWithName ?

Comment: @Chuck The `recipes` property definition should be in the .h for the subclass for the `Type` entity - but if you are not using a subclass, there is no need for this definition.  You should ensure that the relationship between `Type` and `Recipe` is set up correctly as *to-many*.  Not sure why the FRC cache should affect things; can you show the error from the crash?  Also, it's better to edit your question and add code/errors there instead of adding comments.

Comment: Wow - Thank you for extending such kind advice for second time poster. I was really scared to post for fear someone would just laugh and tell me to study the Apple dox. You have been ultra nice. I will rework the error and post it shortly and will show the code edits in my question, per your suggestions. Only one other point here. Do I need the FRC caches to be in both tableviews classes with types and recipes? Or do I only need to reference the cache in the first table? And, Do I need the cache at all?

Comment: @Chuck The FRC cache hold details of which objects are in which sections - so you should not use the same cache name for separate FRCs (unless they are showing *exactly* the same information).  In your case they show completely different information, so if you want both to use a cache, use different cache names.  But caches are not necessary.  They speed things up if you have a large number of objects, but I doubt they will make any appreciable difference in your case.